Validate record on update by doing callout
Question:
If any one is updating the status of Project as Live, I want to first validate it by doing a callout and if response is success then allow the status to be updated as Live, else show error message.
I know we have some limitations here, as callout can only be possible in future method in trigger.
One of the possible solution is prio callout before making status as Live, and I will store the success or failed response in any field and use this value as validation while going live.
But can anyone please suggest any other possible solution to prevent additional User click.

One solution to this would be to utilise Flow within a Quick Action on the object rather than allowing them to update the status directly.
With this approach, you'd need to create a Screen Flow which makes the callout to validate the status, and if successful updates the status to Live. If the callout isn't successful/the status shouldn't be updated yet, you could display an error or warning message to the user.
You'd need to ensure that you don't provide edit access on the layout to update the status, and could consider saving the response from the callout into a field on the object to enable you to utilise a Validation Rule that prevents the status being updated to Live without having checked the external system.

Hi Callum, Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please let me know if I can anyhow validate the record in while updating the Status to Live? I will definitely use the above mentioned solution if there are no other possibilities.
